# remove object from 2 layer nested JSONB[] column

Tags: database, postgresql

Here I how my data is in the column

```json
[
  {
    "exercises": [
      {
        "exercise_name": "test",
        "exercise_video": {
          "media_id": "id_1",
          "video_url": "URL",
          "media_name": "HIIT.mp4",
          "video_play_at": 0,
          "is_video_muted": true,
          "video_duration": 0,
          "video_play_duration": 120,
          "is_video_play_in_loop": true
        },
        "show_countdown": true,
        "show_to_participants": false,
        "exercise_duration_in_seconds": 120
      },
      {
        "exercise_name": "test1",
        "exercise_video": {
          "media_id": "id_2",
          "video_url": "URL",
          "media_name": "HIIT.mp4",
          "video_play_at": 0,
          "is_video_muted": true,
          "video_duration": 0,
          "video_play_duration": 120,
          "is_video_play_in_loop": true
        },
        "show_countdown": true,
        "show_to_participants": false,
        "exercise_duration_in_seconds": 120
      }
    ],
    "segment_icon": "Barre",
    "segment_name": "test",
    "segment_duration_in_seconds": 120
  }
]
```

I need to remove entire exercise_video object if media_id = id_2. Expected final result

```json
[                                          
  {                                        
    "exercises": [                         
      {                                    
        "exercise_name": "test",           
        "exercise_video": {                
          "media_id": "id_1",              
          "video_url": "URL",              
          "media_name": "HIIT.mp4",        
          "video_play_at": 0,              
          "is_video_muted": true,          
          "video_duration": 0,             
          "video_play_duration": 120,      
          "is_video_play_in_loop": true    
        },                                 
        "show_countdown": true,            
        "show_to_participants": false,     
        "exercise_duration_in_seconds": 120
      },                                   
      {                                    
        "exercise_name": "test1",          
        "show_countdown": true,            
        "show_to_participants": false,     
        "exercise_duration_in_seconds": 120
      }                                    
    ],                                     
    "segment_icon": "Barre",               
    "segment_name": "test",                
    "segment_duration_in_seconds": 120     
  }                                        
]
```

```sql
WITH updated_activity AS (
    SELECT activity_id, 
            ('{exercises,'||index-1||',exercise_video.media_id}')::text[] as path
    FROM    activity,
            jsonb_array_elements(
                (workout_builder_test->>'exercises')::jsonb->'exercise_video'
                ) with ordinality arr(x,index)
    WHERE   x->> 'media_id' = 'id_2'
    )
UPDATE  activity 
SET     workout_builder_test = workout_builder_test #- updated_activity.path 
FROM    updated_activity 
WHERE   activity.activity_id = updated_activity.activity_id 
AND     activity.gym_id = 'gym_id'
```

Comment: And what went wrong when you create that unknown piece of SQL? And what function didn't work as you expected? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: I'm trying to remove the exercise_video object if media_id = id_2 matches. But it's not working. I have added the query as well. @FrankHeikens

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close, just some problems with your paths. Here an example with paths mended:

```
SELECT activity_id, 
jsonb_pretty( workout_builder_test #- ('{0,exercises,'||e.i-1/*index of part to remove*/||',exercise_video}')::text[])  
from activity, jsonb_array_elements(workout_builder_test->0->'exercises') with ordinality as e(cont, i)
where e.cont->'exercise_video'->'media_id'='"id_2"';
```

working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bee00/3)